# Count MongoDB Logs Errors on a Remote Server

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I'm Trying run to the following query (Custom Count of the Errors in logs):

```
db.getCollection('logs').count({
    "timestamp" : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1)},
    "level" : "error",
    "message" : {$not: {$regex:  ".*sso"}}
    })
```

On a Remote MongoDB Cluster, using a certificate based authentication.

Typicality,
I will use the `--eval` flag to call a `.js` script.

But due to a security reasons, i can't save files locally.

So I tried using the following syntax combinations:

`1. echo -e ''`:

```
echo -e 'db.getCollection('logs').count({"timestamp" : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1)},"level" : "error","message" : {$not: {$regex:  ".*sso"}}})' | mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /mongodb/certificate/test.pem --sslCAFile /mongodb/certificate/testCA.pem  --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --host MyServer.MyDomain --quiet --port 27019
```

`2. echo $''`:

```
echo $'db.getCollection('logs').count({"timestamp" : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1)},"level" : "error","message" : {$not: {$regex:  ".*sso"}}})' | mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /mongodb/certificate/test.pem --sslCAFile /mongodb/certificate/testCA.pem  --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --host MyServer.MyDomain --quiet --port 27019
```

`3. printf ''`:

```
printf 'db.getCollection('logs').count({"timestamp" : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1)},"level" : "error","message" : {$not: {$regex:  ".*sso"}}})' | mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /mongodb/certificate/test.pem --sslCAFile /mongodb/certificate/testCA.pem  --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --host MyServer.MyDomain --quiet --port 27019
```

To pass the query, to the `mongo` shell command.

But i'm getting the same error, each time, that logs is not defined :

```
2021-10-25T17:06:04.260+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: logs is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Not sure exactly what is the problem, it seems that i need to escape some charter. but i didn't find any documentation.

Comment: What about `db.logs` instead of `db.getCollection('logs')`? The same result?

Comment: You are delimiting your string with `'`, so you effectively have the string `'db.getCollection('` followed by `logs` then another string.  Try using `"logs"`

Comment: @Joe, Can you please elaborate?
Because i'm delimiting the whole string using single quotes ('), and not only the `'logs'`. to prevent the Linux shell, from evaluating the `mongo` operators in my query (starting with the $ sign), as an environment variables.

Comment: You have four `'` in that line, which means 2 strings.  Try just echoing to stdout instead of piping to mongo, so you can see the result.

Comment: @Joe,  thanks now i have understand what is the issue, but please correct if i wrong, but `echo -e`/`echo $`/`printf` does prints to `stdout`. so i didn't actually understand your recommendation to echo to `stdout` instead of piping to `mongo`. it seems i'm already doing it.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the command you are actually sending to mongo starts with `db.getCollection(logs)` (note the distinct lack of quotation marks) and directing that to your screen instead of to the stdin of a mongo shell will help you see it.